# iMacros wait until page loads

Tags: imacros

I used to use iMacros all the time and to make the macro wait for the page to load it  was as simple as:
SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES 
However now this doesn't work and it seems from the iMacros website http://wiki.imacros.net/!WAITPAGECOMPLETE that this feature isn't even compatible with Firefox anymore.

What is an alternative way of doing this other than waiting a specified amount of time? Surely there must be, why would subsequent version regress?

Thanks in advance
P.S. Reverting back to IE  is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
```

Then you will increase waiting time for a page to 120 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to do this without specifying a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

```
!WAITPAGECOMPLETE
```

Available after version 7.40

https://wiki.imacros.net/!WAITPAGECOMPLETE