# How to write imacro to scroll to bottom

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to create a macro that just scrolls down to the bottom of the page on a typical "endless" page such as Facebook.  Then I will Set the Max Loop and click "Play (Loop)" based on how long I want it to go.
IMacro 9.0.3 in Firefox 49.0.1.

```
'SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20)
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

It runs for maybe 20 seconds, then gets error:

> Page loading timeout, URL: javascript:window.scrollBy(0,2000), line: 3
>   (Error code: -802)

If I include the !WAITPAGECOMPLETE, I get this error:

> Unsupported variable !WAITPAGECOMPLETE, line: 1 (Error code: -911)

Alternatively I tried the timeout based on this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626005/imacros-wait-until-page-loads).

```
'SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 3
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,2000)
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

and it often gets this error (even when I just click the "Play" vs the "Play (loop)" button.

> Page loading timeout, URL: javascript:window.scrollBy(0,2000), line: 3
>   (Error code: -802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play the following code in loop mode:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

Comment: I'm at work, will try later.  Is 35 down arrow?  Is that ASCII or where did you get the code 35 for the key?

Comment: 35 is the 'End' key. Simply recorded with 'Experimental event recording mode'.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, it works great!  Their documentation must be bad if I couldn't figure it out - I've only been doing computers for 37 years or so!